# Using NSTimer to get accurate timings

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I need to run my game loop with very accurate timing. I am trying to use NSTimer to do this, and I am getting ok results, but there is a bit of drift.
When NSTimer fires does the next time event start counting when the handler finishes or does it start counting straight away. 
If the former is it reasonable for me to use setFireDate to try to offset the next timer firing - when I tried this things seemed worse.

My timer is set to fire every 44ms and I would like to stop it drifting by more than 20ms. If it does drift I would like to correct it for the next fire.
Is this a reasonable thing to try and do with NSTimer?

Comment: 20ms on 44ms is not drift, that's inaccurate. NSTImer should be much more reliable than that.

Comment: I think what I was trying to say was that I want the time my loop runs to not drift. From what I can tell the timer starts its next timing at the point the handler exits so the time actually seems to be timer value + game upate time.

Comment: It's certainly not supposed to drift like that according to the documentation (and I've found that to be true in the past when I wrote a simple mouse-tracker).  If it is drifting, you should file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Checking the documentation again, I think you are correct. Also, it states that the next scheduled time is based on the original scheduled time not when it actually fired. As Daniel pointed out below though the effective resolution is 50-100ms so it maybe that I am falling victim to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try creating a thread and scheduling your timer on that thread's run loop. Having that timer as the only thing on that run loop should limit the number of things that can interfere with it.

If that doesn't work, well, you'll already have it working on a thread, so you may as well switch to a usleep() loop.

Comment: I am going to try this. It will be a while before I can report back though

Comment: I ended up using [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval] and mach_absolute_time. Timing is now spot on.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think NSTimer will give you "very" accurate timing.  It fires on the run loop, so if it's in your main thread then it'll get delayed by everything from UI updates to event handling.

Comment: when I say very accurate, I mean I don't want it to drift by more than say 20ms. my timer fires every 44ms, when it does drift I would like to correct the next firing. In fact I think I'll update the question with this info

Comment: The doc for NSTimer says the timing is always based on the original interval from when it's started.  That means it shouldn't "drift", but it can have "jitter".  The doc also claims an effective resolution of 50 - 100 ms.

Comment: Hmm that is probably not an accurate enough resolution for me. I have managed to get the variance down quite a lot by adjusting the fireDate based on time since last fire. Maybe I need to look into usleep() timing mentioned by Peter Hosey.

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind that the NSTimer documentation states:

> Because of the various input sources a
>   typical run loop manages, the
>   effective resolution of the time
>   interval for a timer is limited to on
>   the order of 50-100 milliseconds. If a
>   timer’s firing time occurs while the
>   run loop is in a mode that is not
>   monitoring the timer or during a long
>   callout, the timer does not fire until
>   the next time the run loop checks the
>   timer. Therefore, the actual time at
>   which the timer fires potentially can
>   be a significant period of time after
>   the scheduled firing time.